# How to implement div break similar to page break in print?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I have a situation where I have to break text content from one div to another of fixed heights in case maximum height is reached 
Is there a simple function in JavaScript or css to achieve it .

I have partially achieved it by calculating inner height of each list item . But it isn't feasible since it moves entire list item to next div if size is too big leaving a empty space on current div .

*Abc
*Def
*Ghi
*Jklmnopjjskxnxkxnxbxxnxjjxxn
Bjjskskdjdjdjjdk
Hdusisjsj
*Jdkkdoerkdnd

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with sample input/output?

Comment: lets see some code

Comment: I have reposted question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973662/how-to-achieve-print-preview-functionality-with-css-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Thing your require is "[CSS Regions](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-css-regions/)" but it still has [poor support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions) across the browsers.

You can try [polifill](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-regions-polyfill) but I'm not sure it can break list item between regions as you mentioned.

UPD or maybe [CSS Mutlicolumn Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns) could be enough for you since it has [better support](https://caniuse.com/#search=column) as for now

Comment: I have reposted question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973662/how-to-achieve-print-preview-functionality-with-css-and-javascript